# ROCR Prediction/Perfromance

Tags: regression, machine-learning, logistic, rocr

I am having problem with the understanding of ROCR package , following are my questions please clarify my concept

1)What prediction and performance function does in ROCR?

2)If a model has overall accuracy 83% at 0.5 threshold , using ROCR AUC is 67%. is this 67% Overall area under curve?

```
 > table(test$not.fully.paid,predicted.risk>0.5)

    FALSE TRUE
  0  2400   13
  1   457    3

> pred = prediction(test$predicted.risk, test$not.fully.paid)
> as.numeric(performance(pred, "auc")@y.values)
[1] 0.6720995
```

3) If question 2 answer is yes then which metrics should we use to evaluate the model performance "overall accuracy "or "AUC"?

4)AUC tells us is just area under curve how can it be metrics for the model evaluation?

Regards

Sahil

Comment: The area under the ROC curve is the probability that your model will rank a randomly chosen positive class higher than a randomly chosen negative class: http://madrury.github.io/jekyll/update/statistics/2017/06/21/auc-proof.html.  This makes some sense of your 4.  I'd also like to add that accuracy is not a metric for model evaluation, it is a metric for *decision rule* evaluation.  Models generally produce probabilities, so model evaluation metrics should compare measurements of how well those probabilities reflect the data.

Comment: @MatthewDrury: (+1) Very  nice blog-post! Thanks for taking the time to write it!

Comment: Hi Matthew,

Thanks for clarification. How can we find model is good for deploying

Whether should i check AIC, AUC , Precision, recall or overall accuracy?
Or should i use the combination af all?

Thanks